# Padding in edge causes text to alternate between wrapping and non-wrapping

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Title at least is suggested from my naïve understanding of what is happening. For this question, I am focusing on the top left value '13,239,984,40'.

So in the first image, I have a grid. The red suggests the area taken up by the padding of the number (padding left) and the yellow shows the area taken by the number as well as the $ symbol. One can observe that because the area taken up by the yellow is not enough for the red that it causes a newline means that we are having a 'wrapping text'.

[image: image1]

Next, I increase the width of the column. This allows for the $ to be on the same row as the number.

[image: image2]

What I do now is decrease the value of padding-left to 0. As expected, the two are still on the same line.

[image: image3]

Now, I decrease the width of the column and the two are on the same row. The text extends 'invisibily' into the next column and no new line is created. This suggests that the text is non-wrapping.

[image: image4]

This suggests that:

- padding => wrapping text
- no padding => non-wrapping text

Both the $ and number are within spans and we defined in the css that it should not be wrapping. This only happens in Edge and no other (major) browser. Any non-zero value causes it to act wrapping. I don't need a solution as deleting the padding works. I just want to know why it acts this way.

Comment: This question is going to be difficult to answer without knowing the actual markup inside of the `<td>` element and what types of display/float styles are being applied to the children. It looks like there are possibly floats happening which would cause this behavior. 'no-wrap' styles apply to tags individually. Since the $ is in it's own container element, you cannot keep the row from wrapping the way you understand it. Your expectations could be achieved with the flexbox display model.

Comment: This question is too hard to answer without a reproduction of the problem. Use http://jsfiddle.net/ or your favourite similar site.